# Regular Expressions Python - unicode to plain text

Tags: python, unicode

Anyone know a simple way to do the following?

Given a unicode string containing 'USA' in Chinese (美国), Japanese (米国), or Korean (미국­), write a function that returns a plain Python byte string in which the international version of 'USA' is translated into 'USA' in English.
For example:
 translate_usa(u'美国 is a country.') should return 'USA is a country.'

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Comment: thanks for the help @timgeb! i'm getting u'USA is a country.'  rather than 'USA is a country.'

Comment: That's just a unicode string, you can use it just like a 'normal' string. If you want to, you can get rid of the u prefix by casting the result to str explicitly, for example `str(u'foo')` --> `'foo'`

Comment: got it, thanks! do you know how I can accomplish similar results passing in this string to the function: translate_usa(u'ç¾Žå›½, ç±³å›½ and ë¯¸êµ­ are the same country.')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain `str.replace` or use a regex which matches any of the three strings.

```
>>> import re
>>> usa = (u'ç¾Žå›½', u'ç±³å›½', u'ë¯¸êµ')
>>> re.sub('|'.join(usa), 'USA', u'ç¾Žå›½ is a country.')
u'USA is a country.'
```